# Open ViewController (which is a navigationController within a tabBarController) and run function

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I want to allow the user to open an image up in my app from their email. I have set up functions in the app delegate as follows to navigate to my settingsTableViewController. The settingsTableViewController is a navigationController and that is a tabBarViewController.

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL,
    options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {


    self.window!.visibleViewController
    goToSecond()


    return true
}

func goToSecond() {
        let tabBarController: UITabBarController = (self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController)!
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3

}
```

The extension I used to make the above work was:

```
public extension UIWindow {
public var visibleViewController: UIViewController? {
    return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(self.rootViewController)
}

public static func getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nc = vc as? UINavigationController {
        return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(nc.visibleViewController)
    } else if let tc = vc as? UITabBarController {
        return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(tc.selectedViewController)
    } else {
        if let pvc = vc?.presentedViewController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(pvc)
        } else {
            return vc
        }
    }
}
}
```

The above works until I add my code in to pass the url to the settingsTableViewController as follows:

```
let vc = self.window?.rootViewController as! SettingsTableViewController
    vc.displayImage(url)
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type '.TabBarController' (0x100161c00) to '.SettingsTableViewController'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your error tells you exactly what the problem is. The RVC is actually a `TabBarController`, not your `SettingsTableViewController`. This means you need to access the `TabBarController`'s `viewController` array until you arrive at your `SettingsTableViewController`